# shardCollection vs. insert race condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

It seems there's a race condition in Mongo between calling shardCollection and inserting into the same collection, during an operation called createFirstChunks. This is documented in a comment in [the Mongo source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/s/chunk.cpp#L1000) which says:

> TODO: Race condition if we shard the collection and insert data while we split across non-primary shard.

Someone has apparently encountered this race condition in real life, and it broke that collection in his database ([bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10653)).

After calling shardCollection, how do I know it's definitely safe to begin inserting? Is it enough for the call to shardCollection to complete, or do I need to poll the results of some other call?

Comment: it is enough for the call to shardCollection() to complete (it returns   ok:1 if it succeeds).

Comment: btw, are you sharding a new collection or an existing one? and are you using hashed shard key when sharding it or regular?

Comment: I'm sharding a new (empty) collection before inserting. I use different keys for different collections, some hashed, some not, by design.

Comment: If you're sure it's enough for shardCollection to succeed (how do you know this? can you provide a reference or are you a Mongo committer? etc) then please make that an answer.

Comment: basically, the race has to do with some of collections' chunks being on a different shard than the primary - but that's not possible when it's an empty collection unless it has a hashed shard key (in which case regular balancing operations distribute the chunks around).  The linked case is a different problem - they had an attempt to enableSharding on a collection fail which left the chunks meta-data collection in state inconsistent from the state in other meta-data collections.

Comment: see my answer with code reference and explanation of what the related ticket actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The race condition does not apply to the case where you, the user/admin/application create a new collection or shard an existing connection.

Note that the comment references race when splitting across non-primary shard - normally when a collection is "sharded" a single chunk is defined which lives on the shard that's the primary home to the database that collection is in.  `sh.status()` shows which shard is primary for each database in your cluster.

There are two separate commands that invoke the `shardCollection` class (which is the only place that `createFirstChunks` is called from).  One is the admin command `enableSharding` which is what you are calling.  The other is the internal workings of `MapReduce` when it's required to create a new sharded collection for its output.  You can [see that call here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/s/commands_public.cpp#L1579).

Since you are not exercising the code path that is potentially prone to this hypothetical race condition, I don't believe you need to worry about it.

The case you linked as possibly manifestation of this "race" actually hit a different problem.   They attempted to shard a collection and part way through the operation something happened and the command failed.   Since the chunks collection already got created it left their cluster in a state where repeat of shardCollection command would fail.  This deficiency is tracked in [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5160).

I hope this is sufficient for you to conclude that after shardCollection command returns with success status, you can safely proceed to insert data into it.  Even if the collection already exists and has inserts coming in, sharding it should not interfere nor cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and researched answer!